# A more efficient way to parse the elements of a nested list

Tags: r

I'm developing [a function that parses a nested list](http://github.com/rmscriven/saber/blob/master/R/load-event.R).  Unfortunately, because of the nature of the raw data, there's really no way I can think of to get around doing it this way.  The final three bits of code in the function scare me a little, but they do get the job done.  Here they are:

```
mkList <- lapply(rec, function(x){
      lapply(regex, function(y) grep(y, x, value = TRUE)) })
rem <- lapply(mkList, function(x){
      lapply(x, function(y) sub("[a-z]+,", "", y)) })
lapply(rem, read.as.csv)
```

Yes, you're seeing that correctly, it's 5 consecutive calls to `lapply`.  And yes, you guessed it, `read.as.csv` also calls `lapply`

---

To make a small reproducible example, consider the nested list `x` and the next "double" `lapply` chunk.  The result is exactly  what I want, but I'm curious

**Is there a better, more efficient way to apply a function to the inner list of a nested list?**

The inner list elements are csv vectors of varying string length.

```
> ( x <- list(list(a = c("a,b,c", "d,e,f"), 
                   b = c("1,2,a,b,c,d", "3,4,e,f,g,h"))) )

# [[1]]
# [[1]]$a
# [1] "a,b,c" "d,e,f"
#
# [[1]]$b
# [1] "1,2,a,b,c,d" "3,4,e,f,g,h"

> lapply(x, function(y){
      lapply(y, function(z) do.call(rbind, strsplit(z, ",")))
  })

# [[1]]
# [[1]]$a
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "a"  "b"  "c" 
# [2,] "d"  "e"  "f" 
# 
# [[1]]$b
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,] "1"  "2"  "a"  "b"  "c"  "d" 
# [2,] "3"  "4"  "e"  "f"  "g"  "h"
```

Comment: Are you looking for `rapply` perhaps? `rapply(x, function(y) do.call(rbind, strsplit(y, ",", TRUE)), how = "replace")`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, you are becoming the reason why I ask questions late at night.  Haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Among the lesser-known functions in the `*apply` family is `rapply`--for "recursive `lapply`". It seems like you're trying to do:

```
rapply(x, function(y) do.call(rbind, strsplit(y, ",", TRUE)), how = "replace")
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$a
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "a"  "b"  "c" 
# [2,] "d"  "e"  "f" 
# 
# [[1]]$b
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,] "1"  "2"  "a"  "b"  "c"  "d" 
# [2,] "3"  "4"  "e"  "f"  "g"  "h"
```

For this particular example, it's a shade behind your approach, but as you scale the example up, it proves to be more efficient.

Comment: I'll give them both a whirl through `system.time`.

Comment: You know what, I am passing two variables in. In the first, `rec` and `regex` both go in.  Can I use two variables in `rapply` like I can in `mapply`? The help file says `f` is a function of a single variable

Comment: @RichardScriven, not tested, but isn't that what the `...` is for in `rapply`? (It's defined as *additional arguments passed to the call to `f`.*)

Comment: Looks like it will work on the second, but I may need to re-think the first.  Perhaps I'll break those calls up.  Also `lapply(rec, function(x) lapply(regex, grep, x, value = TRUE))` is also much faster than the way I wrote it..

Comment: @RichardScriven, wouldn't it also make more sense to break out the downloading step from your function and store it in a `tempdir()` or something? Seems like an abuse of bandwidth to have to re-download for each team. (Unless I'm reading your code incorrectly.)

Comment: You're right.  I'm still mulling this over.  I may end up sticking the zipped files in the `data` directory of the package